# mongoose default value equal to other value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For my project i've created an userSchema which simplified looks like the following:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    screenname: {type: String, required: false, default: "equal _id"},
});
```

The user has an _id that is a string which also is his username.
Everything works so far until i tried to add an extra field screenname. What i want is when the user creates an account, his screenname equals the value of _id.  Later he can adjust it but by default it should equal the value of _id. i've also tried :

```
 screenname: {type: String, required: false, default: _id},
```

But than ofcourse _id is not defined.

How should i set the default value to equal another value ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use the `pre` middleware explained [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.screenname = this.get('_id'); // considering _id is input by client
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 16):

You can pass a function to default, following is a schema field excerpt:

```
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    // fix for missing usernames causing validation fail
    default: function() {
        const _t = this as any; // tslint:disable-line
        return _t.name || _t.subEmail;
    }
},
```

Comment: This worked wonderful for me,
`@Prop({
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: function () {
      return this.name || this.email.split('@')[0];
    },
  })
  name: string;`

Comment: There's a catch in this. You can not use arrow functions for the default value.

For eg. the below code will always return the same value which is 7.


```default: () => Math.random(). // lets say output 0.7```

Comment: @Ram as per latest version (7.5.0) you can use arrow functions. This code in my case generates random uuid's every time I call *create*: `uuid: { type: String, default: () => crypto.randomUUID() }`